# Difference in single thread performance between 2 CPU's

Tags: threads

What’s the difference in single thread performance between Intel(R) Xenon(R) CPU E5-2697 v2 @ 2.70GHz 2.69 GHz & Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz?

Comment: http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/434/Intel_Core_i7_i7-4770_vs_Intel_Xeon_E5-2697_v2.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best guide is the
[PassMark CPU benchmarks](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html).

The *Intel Xeon E5-2697 v2 @ 2.70GHz* got the mark of 17,217,
while the *Intel Core i7-4770 @ 3.40GHz* is noted at 9,780.

The E5-2697 is then about twice as fast as the i7-4770 according to the
PassMark benchmark.

Regarding
[Single Thread Performance](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/singleThread.html),
the *Intel Xeon E5-2697 v2 @ 2.70GHz* got the mark of 1,732,
while the *Intel Core i7-4770 @ 3.40GHz* is noted at 2,227.
The i7 is now faster.

The E5-2697 has 12 cores, while the i7 has 4.
This is the eternal problem when comparing CPUs that have many cores
with ones that have only few, when they are using similar technologies
(both your CPUs are from Q2 2013).
In many cases, the multi-core CPU will be faster on throughput,
while the few-core CPU will be faster on single-core performance.

Your choice should be dictated by the workload that you would be running
on the computer.
Please note that the CPU is not the only component that is important for
performance, there are others like RAM and disk that can become
bottlenecks even for a rapid CPU.

Comment: But he was asking about single thread performance though. According to PassMark the i7 is actually faster in this scenario

Comment: @JamesP: Accroding to the Single Thread Performance benchmark, the ratio is still almost exactly the same.

Comment: The figure I am seeing for the i7 is 2,227

Comment: @JamesP: Strange, there are two entries for the i7. This becomes somewhat unreliable.

Comment: There are many i7 processors if you include K, U and so on. You'd also be much better of using the pass mark comparison tool to see the actual figures. For pure single threaded performance the i7 easily beats the xeon. https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-Xeon-E5-2697-v2-vs-Intel-i7-4770/2009vs1907

Comment: @Mokubai: I was probably looking at the wrong variant. I modified my answer to use the PassMark figure of 2,227.